# Firebase query methods are not working for me, I can't seem to find any of the methods

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

Query does not contain a definition for 'once' and no accessable extension method 'once'. Maybe I am being really stupid but I am having tons of issues with this.

This is for database to check to see if a user already exists if not create a user or load their data.

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
        databaseReference.Child("users").OrderByChild("users").once("value", snapshot =>
        {
            if (snapshot.exists())
            {
                GetUserData(user);
            }

        });
```

Comment: Well if you look at the [API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/query) you can see that as the exception says in `Query` there is no such method called `once` .. what are you trying to achieve? Maybe [LimitToFirst](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/query#class_firebase_1_1_database_1_1_query_1a5d94502e61cf238e6a2c86459dfff806) is what you are after?

Comment: Is "Query does not contain a definition for 'once' and no accessable extension method 'once'" an error you are getting? If so, please place it in a quote block, and prefix it with "This is the error I am getting". Also, it looks like it has a spelling error in it: it is best to copy+paste the error, so readers can see the real thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `once()` method only exists in the JavaScript SDK for the Firebase Realtime Database.

The equivalent in the Unity clients is `GetValueAsync`, as shown in the documentation on [reading data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data#read_data_once).

From there:

> ```
>  FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
>   .GetReference("Leaders")
>   .GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
>     if (task.IsFaulted) {
>       // Handle the error...
>     }
>     else if (task.IsCompleted) {
>       DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
>       // Do something with snapshot...
>     }
>   });
> ```

Comment: Yeah I finally figured it out. I inspected the query class did not find the methods for it but after reading the firebase page after taking a break I figured out it sends a null task result if empty therefore I can add new users!